# Can't change my default terminal in AwesomeWM to Alacritty

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, awesome

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04/AwesomeWM trying to set the default terminal as Alacritty. I can run it in the terminal with the `alacritty` command and it pop-up on my screen with no problems, but when I change the value of the `terminal` variable of my `rc.lua` from

```lua
terminal = "x-terminal-emulator"
```

to

```lua
terminal = "alacritty"
```

And restart Awesome with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. The command <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> don't run any terminal, it does nothing.

Another thing that I tried to do was to change the function from the shortcut <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> from

```lua
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "Return", function () awful.spawn(terminal) end,
              {description = "open a terminal", group = "launcher"}),
```

to

```lua
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "Return", function () awful.spawn.with_shell("alacritty") end,
              {description = "open a terminal", group = "launcher"}),
```

But as you might know, nothing happened. Any solution?

Comment: Can you check with `which alacritty` the command that is used ?
Perhaps it is a local PATH issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm not on Ubuntu, but I had the same problem. This solution worked for me:

```
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "Return", function () awful.spawn.with_shell("LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 alacritty") end,
   {description = "open a terminal", group = "launcher"}),
```

The key is

```
"LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 alacritty"
```

The issue with GLSL 3.30 I was running into is explained here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Alacritty#Requires_hardware_supporting_GLSL_3.30

Comment: this worked (virtualbox + alacritty). but for some reason the env setting in this form is not accepted in the general 'terminal' variable that is used elsewhere throughout the conf (so was not able to get the menu item for terminal working, only the shortcut)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use your full path to the program:

```
terminal = "/full/path/to/alacritty"
```